# Xamarin iOS : Facebook logout issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Facebook.iOS [SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios) (v 4.13.1.0) for Facebook login.

**Current scenario:**
In my app, once user logs in through Facebook credentials and logs out, he can just hit login and get authenticated.

**Expected Scenario:**
Once user logs in through Facebook credentials and logs out, if he wants to login again, he needs to enter his Facebook is and password once again.

Right now for log out I am using the following code:

```
NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
            foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies) 
            {
                if(cookie.Domain == ".facebook.com")
                {
                    storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
                }
        }
```

But this doesn't work. Right now, to get the expected result I have to:

1. Sign out and close app, then Open Safari and clear history.
2. Sign out and close app, then Open Safari -> goto Facebook website ( it won't ask for credentials as it was has when we logged in it from our app) and logout.

Clearly, its not the best way to get the desired result. Can anyone please advise me a better approach ??

Also, Is there any way I could set expiry date for the Facebook access token that way i could set the expiry date to current date time and let user enter his credentials again next time they login.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded the iPhone with iOS 10.1.1 and now the logout work correctly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14225999)

Comment: The answer is here "I upgraded the iPhone with iOS 10.1.1 and now the logout work correctly".

Comment: I link my post on Xamarin Forum but the solution is on the answer above: "only upgrade". Thanks for the suggest Joshua